# x86 RET behaviour

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gdb

I am trying to execute a ROP chain on a 32 bit Ubuntu 11.10 machine and the RET instruction seems to behave in an unexpected way.

I am building the payload using python like this:

```
p += pack("&lt;I", 0x8049b4f) # pop eax ; add esp 0x5c; ret;
p += "\\\u609b\\\u0000" # system - srand offset  
p += "A"*0x5c # this is needed because of add esp 0x5c from the previous instruction
p += pack("&lt;I", 0x8048bf0) # pop ebx ; ret;  
p += pack("&lt;I", (0x0804bcd4 - 0x5d5b04c4) & 0xffffffff)  
p += pack("&lt;I", 0x80493fe) # add [ebx+0x5d5b04c4] eax; ret;
```

The addresses used are from the .text section of the executable. No addresses from shared libraries are used.

My code jumps to 0x8049b4f, pops the value from line 2 into EAX, adds 0x5c to ESP and calls RET.

Everything works as expected and EIP jumps to 0x8048bf0.

POP EBX is executed, moving the value from line 5 into EBX

The next instruction is a RET, which should pop the top value from the stack (which is 0x80493fe) into EIP. When RET is executed, I get:

Cannot access memory at address 0x41414145

At this moment EIP points at 0x80493fe (as expected), and the top value from ESP was poped.

When the program flow starts executing my ROP chain (so, before EIP is at 0x8049b4f from line 1), ESI, EDI and EBP all contain 0x41414141

Somehow the RET from line 4 tries do to something with ESI/EDI/EBP+4 (EBP most likely), but what?

Why does this happen? What am I missing?

I have added screenshots of the debug process here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9sickyhmryop27y/AADIHbIPE177PCu3fmqsVFKpa?dl=0

Comment: This is not a fault with the program, it's just gdb trying to access memory (probably to fetch info about the stack frame). You can ignore this message. Faults in your code are going to be indicated with a proper signal. You should be able to continue executing normally.